# How to stop img from overflowing?

Tags: html, css

My problem is that I have an image that I would like to use as the logo for the website. The header and div that it is in are properly sized (i checked by inspecting it on chrome) , but the img is overflowing. How do i scale it down?
(I will use a placeholder image for the code)
Here is the code:

```
<body>
  <header class="mainheader">
     <a href="main.html" class="navelement">
        <div class="imgcontainer">
          <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Ajc8gSO3SRw/VtZj0tsyXhI/AAAAAAAAAHs/tlsdyufJ1J4/w868-h560/2.png"/>
        </div>
    </a>
  </header>
 </body>
```

Here is the accompanying css, I'm confused why the max-height isn't working.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
 body{
   margin: 0;
}
header{
  height:10vh;
  width: 100%;
  float left:
  margin: 0;
  background-color:grey;
  font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}
header .navElement {
  vertical-align: middle;
  float:left;
  width: 17%;
}
.imgcontainer{
  float:left;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.imgcontainer img{
  float:left;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

I realize some things are unnecessary but its because i've tried so much to fix it that i don't know what works. Thanks for any helpful replies.

Comment: "I realize some things are unnecessary but its because i've tried so much to fix it that i don't know what works."  
Make regular save of your work, or work with tutorial, so you will be able to go back easily from a erroneous version to a more reliable one.

Comment: Set a background image, its easier, and you can specify: `background-size:cover;` for it

Comment: Make sure to clear your elements! You have 3 or 4 `float` elements in there, all at different nested levels, but not a single `clear`.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent overflowing of content, you can simply use the corresponding css-property: `overflow: hidden`. If you do so, the content which is overflowing, will simply get cut off. In your example, this wouldn't be the right approach.

Instead of using `max-height` you may use `height`. By doing so, you'll assign an absolute value for your elements. Since your `.imagecontainer` only has a `max-height` property, try replacing it with `height`, as shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8b6Lew21/1/).

```
.imgcontainer {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This appears to work at first but once i add a margin to the img it overflows again.

Comment: Use `padding` instead.